# Twitter Bootstrap Forms in Modal Tab Index Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tabindex

I have a form inside of a twitter bootstrap modal, but the tab-index is not working. I have tried editing the tab-index attribute of the modal but nothing seems to affect it. Goal is that user can tab between form fields. Example can be seen at hookahi.com,  the 'join' links trigger modals with registration forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this code in your page :

```
jQuery('[tabindex]').each(function() { 
    console.log(jQuery(this).attr('tabindex'));
});
```

As you can see, you have many dom items with the same `tabindex`. So the browser just do what it can. If you want a correct behavior with the tab key, each `tabindex` must be used only once.

Comment: Oh okay yes, thanks after this I went and found my form software has a way to set the starting tabindex for each one. Thanks for the help

Comment: This script helped me to debug tabindex errors. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score -1):

put `tabindex="-1"` in modal window and remove remain `tabindex` of inputs in modal window.It solved my problem.You can try.